# How to consume secured REST API in WSO2 EI

Tags: rest, ssl, curl, wso2

Trying to consume secured REST API using WSO2 EI which is having three certificates (‘abc.key’, ‘xyz.pem’ and ‘ryz.crt’)

Using keytool command able to import wyr.crt and xyz.pem certificates but not able to install abc.key certificate.I guess because of that receiving below error when hit the service:

```
ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetHandler} -  I/O error: General SSLEngine problem {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetHandler}
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1478)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:535)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.writeAppRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1214)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.wrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:1186)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:469)
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doWrap(SSLIOSession.java:237)
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:271)
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.isAppInputReady(SSLIOSession.java:410)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:119)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:159)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:338)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:316)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:277)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:586)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1728)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:304)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1514)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1026)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:966)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:963)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1416)
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doRunTask(SSLIOSession.java:255)
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:293)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:281)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:136)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1501)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
        ... 23 more
```

Can somebody help me how to import abc.key certificates into WSO2 EI or i am missing anything?

when i tried importing using keytool giving below message:

```
    ///security>keytool -import -alias abc -file "/home/security/abc.key" -keystore client-truststore.jks -storepass wso2carbon
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate
```

With curl able access the rest service, same thing need to do with WSO2.
sample:

```
curl -i -N -X POST  \
https://xxxx/xxxx-xx-xxxx \
--key ../abc.key \
--cacert ../xyz.pem \
--cert ../ryz.crt \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
-H 'Content-Type: xxx/xxxx' \
-d '{
      "some body
}'
```

Comment: When you say you are not able to import the certificate what exactly is occuring?  What message/error does it give you?  That error you provided looks like the error from when you call an API and not from a certificate import.

Comment: Based on the keytool output looks like you need to provide a password after -storepass

Comment: sorry my bad, Now updated my post...

Comment: What is the abc.key file?  We always use the DER encoded binary x.509 exported as abc.cer and have no issues importing into the client truststore.

Comment: abc.key contains RSA private key and it has provided by client.I just wanted understand one thing if there is any other way to import this kind of certificate into client truststore? or need to convert into abc.cer and import?

Comment: I have never used a clients private key in our client truststore.  I have always used just the *.cer file and never had any issues.

Comment: @jchaplin, Thank you. created PKCS12 keystore and able to import, But still getting same error _javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem_  any solution/clues for this?

Comment: Just for verification....Did you restart the wso2 service after adding the certificate to the clienttruststore?

Comment: @jchaplin, Yes Restarted

Comment: Whenever we have to hit a new one we go the site in a browser, export the certificate using the DER Encoded binary X 509 (CER) option.  I then import that .cer into my client truststore, restart the wso2 service and SSL handshake error no longer occurs.  If you are doing that and it is still occuring I am not sure what to try next.

Comment: I tried this option as well, but For that site Not able to export certificate from browser, export option is disabled for that  particular service I don't know why?